# Play sound via phone speaker during handsfree phone call

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

How to play sound in phone speaker during phone call (in handsfree)?

I try this:

```
audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL, 20, 0);
mediaplayer.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

But in this way - starts playing loud sound from the phone speaker, but the call is terminated in handfree and call is also playing in the phone speaker.

How is it possible to play a sound without affecting the call in handsfree? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [another stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to not interrupt the call audio:

```
mediaplayer.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

If you're just trying to send simple tones over the call itself then maybe:

```
mediaplayer.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF);
```

Comment: Yeah, but other streams automatically plays sound to a bt device... hmm but maybe u are right, cause i'm trying this with my notebook bt adapter (it's not the same like hf), so I need to try handsfree device.